# interaction plot, not plotting a particular value

Tags: r, plot, interaction

I've created an interaction plot and realized that one line breaks in the middle and that is because two factors on the x axis has no value for that particular factor, although for the other factors, it has a value. It looks like this (assume the lines shown are actually connected):

```
  _
/         _ /
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
x axis
```

Basically there is a value for 4, but not for 3 and 5 so that's why it looks as it does. How do I correct this? I have set everything as a factor

I read to use na.rm but that doesn't work and it looks the same.
Thanks

Comment: Please edit with sample data (ideally the results of `dput(yourData)`) and the code you're using to produce your plot.

Comment: Removing the NAs should work - e.g. `dat <- data.frame(x=1:7, y=c(1,3,NA,0,NA,0,2)); plot(na.omit(dat),type="o")`

Comment: I ended up just using segments() and got it working